# HTTP Status 404 when testing restful webservice using Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have been trying to develop and deploy a restful web service using Jersey. I have followed the documentation from docs.oracle.com and also various other sources but getting HTTP Status 404 upon testing the service.

Following is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Hello World</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.rest.jersey.test</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my service.

```
package com.rest.jersey.test;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String response(){
            return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

When I try to hit the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/TestRestWithJersey/resources/hello
```

it gives HTTP Status 404 error. Please help me regarding this.

I just checked log file of Eclipse and it doesn't say anything other than this:

> !MESSAGE No projects found for
>   [/workspace/TestRestWithJersey/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml]

I didn't understand the message, can you help me on this?

Also, the tomcat log when hitting url says

```
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /TestRestWithJersey
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@5362ab
 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I added jersey-server.jar along with jsr-311.jar

Also tried earlier with single jersey-bundle.jar

The problem is still same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try changing u r servletname from Hello to some other and publish and test it!

Comment: do you have jersy jars and dependencies in your lib folder !

Comment: How do you deploy your application?

Comment: What is the name of the war file that you deployed? Do you have an `index.html` file in the root folder of deployed application? If so, can you visit the `http://localhost:8080/TestRestWithJersey/index.html` page from browser?

Comment: What servlet container are you using? Did you look though the log files for any errors?

Comment: @invariant yes I do have all the jars and dependencies in my lib directory.

Comment: @Tom I just used Run As -> Run on Server to deploy and test the app.

Comment: @gotuskar The name of the deployed application is "TestRestWithJersey" and yes, I can access index.html in the browser.

Comment: @creechy I am using servlet container provided by Jersey API. Yes, I just checked log file and it doesn't say anything other than this..

!MESSAGE No projects found for [/workspace/TestRestWithJersey/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml]
I didn't understand the message, can you help me on this?

Comment: @techEnthusiast: Can you try by removing the `<init-param>` part in `web.xml`?

Comment: You may want to step back a bit here. Like try putting a simple index.jsp or index.html file in your project and see if you can access it, just to verify your web-app is even deployed where you are expecting it to be.

Comment: @creechy Yes, web-app is deployed. I can see index.html coming up.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use a servlet container to deploy your application you also need to add [jersey-servlet](http://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-servlet&v=1.15&e=pom) (see [User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1703)) module as a dependency of your project. If you're using maven, simply put

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

into your `pom.xml` file.

If you want to use [jersey-bundle](http://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-bundle&v=1.15&e=jar) instead please make sure you have [asm](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar) on your classpath because package scanning (triggered by `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` init-param in your `web.xml`) needs this library to function properly.

Comment: I still get the ClassNotFoundException on com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.
I am not using Maven, would that be a reason why I am struggling, by any chance?

Comment: Please make sure your `lib` directory is on the build path of your project in Eclipse (and on the app class path on the server as well) - it seems that you have a similar problem to this one [DispatcherServlet not found](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82642-DispatcherServlet-not-found&p=276724#post276724).

Comment: How to check the app class path on the server from my eclipse environment that you have mentioned?

Comment: I also added asm jar mentioned in this answer but still the same issue. I have posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/37177986/1550811