# HTTP Status 404 when running simple RESTful web service in Java using Jersey

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest, jersey, tomcat8

I am getting `HTTP Status 404` when running simple RESTful web service in Java using Jersey. I am following the tutorial [REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#jerseyprojectsetup). I have copied all the jars that I downloaded from [Jersey download site](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) to *WEB-INF/lib* folder of my project(please see the screenshot for jars).

When I run the application from eclipse development environment *Eclipse Console* shows that Tomcat was started successfully. My web-app is deployed  and I can see index.html coming up. But hitting http://localhost:8080/com.kj.rest.jersey.first/ gives Http Status 404.

**My Environment:**

- Spring Tool Suite as my eclipse dev environment
- Jersey 2.22.2 jars
- Apache Tomcat v8.0

Please note I am **not** using Maven in my project and I also looked at other similar questions here but none of them solved my issue.

What am I missing, where should I look for the issue, which logs?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake that I was making was to not specify the service name(specified by `@Path` annotation) in the URL. After doing that it worked.

So essentially the URL to hit should be http://localhost:8080/com.kj.rest.jersey.first/rest/path_from_rest_class and I missed the `path_from_rest_class` earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.*******</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>


  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You have add load on startup ,your jersey engine should start

Comment: I added `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` but still see the same error, no change.

Comment: 404 is the correct answer , What you are expecting, you should hit the link with project name ,to access your project ,your project was working without jersey ?. Test your API with chrome client or fiddler

Comment: Check your console if you dont have any error then your jersey environment is properly setuperd

Comment: Even when I hit http://localhost:8080/com.kj.rest.jersey.first/ I get 404, why should it give that?Moreover eclipse console does not show any error.

Comment: Just to let to you know my web-app is deployed. I can see index.html coming up. but issue is with  localhost:8080/com.kj.rest.jersey.first

Comment: My bad I did not specify the service name(specified by `@Path` annotation) in the URL. After doing that it worked. thanks